Constant identical weight and bias initialisation gives different weights for each neuron of the network
I have read in the notes on some website, as well as in other resources that if the network is intialzed with constant identical weights, then each neuron learns the same weights.
However, when I did the same in tensorflow, i am getting different weights after training for each neuron.
I am following this tutorial
 Here's the important part code:

multi_linear_model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    
    tf.keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: x[:,-1:,:]),

    tf.keras.layers.Dense(OUT_STEPS*num_features,kernel_initializer=tf.initializers.zeros(),bias_initializer=tf.initializers.zeros()),

=    tf.keras.layers.Reshape([OUT_STEPS, num_features])
    
])


I am basically working with time series data. The first lambda layer just extracts the last time stamp. The second layer is a dense layer that operates on this last times step's features with number of neurons defined by the some constants.
The important part is that I have set the weights and biases to zero, But after training, I am getting different weights for each neuron in this layer.
Can someone explain why?? Should this happen or not? Is this a tensorflow thing?Please help..
I was expecting different weights for each neuron in the dense layer. Following is the entire code. Please copy the code to define classes, constants and methods such as WindowGenerator, compile_and_fit, from the link
OUT_STEPS = 24
multi_window = WindowGenerator(input_width=24,
                               label_width=OUT_STEPS,
                               shift=OUT_STEPS)
multi_linear_model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    # Take the last time-step
    # Shape [batch, time, features] => [batch,1,features]
    tf.keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: x[:,-1:,:]),

    # Shape => [batch, out_steps, features]
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(OUT_STEPS*num_features,kernel_initializer=tf.initializers.zeros(),bias_initializer=tf.initializers.zeros()),

    # Shape = [batch, out_steps, features]
    tf.keras.layers.Reshape([OUT_STEPS, num_features])
    
])

multi_linear_model(tf.random.normal((1,24,19))) # to initialze weights

# Extracting weights
weights = multi_linear_model.layers[1].weights[0]

# Printing weights and biases before training
print(weights[0,:10])
print(weights[1,:10])
print(tf.reduce_sum(weights[0])) # sum 0 confirms that all kernel/weights values are zero
print(tf.reduce_sum(weights[1])) # sum 0 confirms that all bias values are zero




# Training

history = compile_and_fit(multi_linear_model, multi_window)


# Printing weights and biases after training
print(weights[0,:10])
print(weights[1,:10])
print(tf.reduce_sum(weights[0])) # sum 0 confirms that all kernel/weights values are zero
print(tf.reduce_sum(weights[1])) # sum 0 confirms that all bias values are zero






This statement is not true for single-layer models.
